# Writing to HBase table from pyspark

Tags: python, hbase, pyspark

The topic is fully covered in example from apache:

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
"""
Create test table in HBase first:
hbase(main):001:0> create 'test', 'f1'
0 row(s) in 0.7840 seconds
> hbase_outputformat <host> test row1 f1 q1 value1
> hbase_outputformat <host> test row2 f1 q1 value2
> hbase_outputformat <host> test row3 f1 q1 value3
> hbase_outputformat <host> test row4 f1 q1 value4
hbase(main):002:0> scan 'test'
ROW                   COLUMN+CELL
 row1                 column=f1:q1, timestamp=1405659615726, value=value1
 row2                 column=f1:q1, timestamp=1405659626803, value=value2
 row3                 column=f1:q1, timestamp=1405659640106, value=value3
 row4                 column=f1:q1, timestamp=1405659650292, value=value4
4 row(s) in 0.0780 seconds
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 7:
        print >> sys.stderr, """
        Usage: hbase_outputformat <host> <table> <row> <family> <qualifier> <value>
        Run with example jar:
        ./bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /path/to/example/jar \
        /path/to/examples/hbase_outputformat.py <args>
        Assumes you have created <table> with column family <family> in HBase
        running on <host> already"""
    exit(-1)
    host = sys.argv[1]
    table = sys.argv[2]
    sc = SparkContext(appName="HBaseOutputFormat")
        conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host,
        "hbase.mapred.outputtable": table,
        "mapreduce.outputformat.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",
        "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
        "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}
        keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"
        valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"
    sc.parallelize([sys.argv[3:]]).map(lambda x: (x[0], x)).saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(
    conf=conf,
    keyConverter=keyConv,
    valueConverter=valueConv)
    sc.stop()
```

But this example assumes that table is already created by hand from hbase shell

Are there any options to create and write to tables from pyspark?

Comment: Please add code here rather than linking to some other website.

Comment: thank you. will never do this in future.